# Multiplying a big (40 bits) unsigned number in TASM?

Tags: assembly, tasm

I have an assigment to multiply an unsigned number of almost any size (i.e. 0x123456789ABCDEF) that's in one file by another number 0x0-F given by parameter, and display the result in another file.

I have the files open and multiplier stored in a variable already, but I can't figure out how to multiply numbers that don't fit in a single (or even two) register. What is the most simple way to do it?

I'll include my code just in case:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h

.DATA
    data_file_name db 150 dup (0)
    result_file_name db 150 dup (0)
    data_handle dw ?
    result_handle dw ?
    data_buffer db 100 dup (?)
    result_buffer db 100 dup (?)
    multiplier db ?
    
    help_message db "Three parameters must be provided: names of the data file, multiplier, name of the result file.$"
    no_result_file db "No result file was provided.$"
    not_txt db "Provided files must have .txt file extension.$"
    error_opening_data_file_message db "Something went wrong trying to open the data file.$"
    error_opening_result_file_message db "Something went wrong trying to open the result file.$"

.CODE
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
    mov bx, 82h ; Pointer to parameter
    mov si, offset data_file_name
    
    ; Print help message if no parameters were provided
    cmp byte ptr es:[80h], 0
    je print_help
    
    ; Print help message if "/?" parameter was provided
    cmp es:[82h], '?/'
    je print_help

main:
    CALL get_file_name
    cmp byte ptr es:[bx], 13
    je print_help
    CALL open_data_file

    inc bx
    mov al, byte ptr es:[bx]
    mov multiplier, al
    inc bx

    mov si, offset result_file_name
    inc bx
    CALL get_file_name
    CALL open_result_file
    ; get result
    ; write result
    ; close data file
    ; close result file
    
    jmp exit     

print_help:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset help_message
    int 21h
    jmp exit

print_no_result_file:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset no_result_file
    int 21h
    jmp exit

print_txt:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset not_txt
    int 21h
    jmp exit
    
error_opening_data_file:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset error_opening_data_file_message
    int 21h
    jmp exit
    
error_opening_result_file:
    mov ah, 9
    mov dx, offset error_opening_result_file_message
    int 21h
    
    ; close data file

    jmp exit

exit:
    mov ah, 4Ch
    int 21h

proc get_file_name
    get_next_character:
    ; Check if end of file name
    cmp byte ptr es:[bx], 32
    je return
    cmp byte ptr es:[bx], 13
    je return
    
    ; Get and store the next character of the file name
    mov al, byte ptr es:[bx]
    mov [si], al
    
    inc bx
    inc si
    jmp get_next_character

    return:
    ret
endp get_file_name

proc open_data_file
    CALL is_text_file

    mov ah, 3Dh ; Open file
    mov al, 0 ; with read access
    mov dx, offset data_file_name
    int 21h
    jc error_opening_data_file

    mov data_handle, ax
    ret
endp open_data_file

proc open_result_file
    CALL is_text_file

    mov ah, 3Dh ; Open file
    mov al, 1 ; with write access
    mov dx, offset result_file_name
    int 21h
    jc error_opening_result_file

    mov result_handle, ax
    ret
endp open_result_file

proc is_text_file
    cmp byte ptr [si-1h], 't'
    jne print_txt
    cmp byte ptr [si-2h], 'x'
    jne print_txt
    cmp byte ptr [si-3h], 't'
    jne print_txt
    cmp byte ptr [si-4h], '.'
    jne print_txt

    ret       
endp is_text_file           

END
```

I've spent a good 4-8 hours looking everywhere for how to do it, but I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Think about how you do manual multiplication by digits. Then consider that 0-9 is arbitrary and can be 0-F or 0-(256) or 0-(65535), etc.